# Can I declare the DirectoryIndex In .htaccess Non-recursively?

Tags: .htaccess, recursion, directoryindex

In my /httpdocs/ folder I need to change the filename of index.php. I did this by writing a new line to my .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index2.php
```

However, it seems that all subfolders under /httpdocs/ were looking for index2.php for their DirectoryIndex file. Is there a way I can alter the DirectoryIndex file for my /httpdocs/ folder without it recursively affecting every folder under it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this...

```
DirectoryIndex index2.php index.php index.html
```

Apache will look from left to right for the index file.

For example, if `index2.php` doesn't exist, it will look for `index.php`.